# Android. Change name of file in pdf viewer

Tags: android, file, pdf, android-intent, rename

Let's say I have following code to display .pdf file:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  startActivity(intent);
```

How can I change the title displayed in pdf viewer so it is different than file name? Maybe I can put some extras to intent?